# What wood should I use on a garage door?

Tags: wood

I have a garage door that has wood on the door itself.

[image]

The wood has not aged very well. It is about 6 years old and has paint coming off of it as well as is starting to fall off of the door. There are also a few pieces that have warped some.

[image]

So my question is, what type of wood should I be using on a door like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like cedar, that is a good wood to use.  One thing to do if you replace it, is seal the ends and backs of the boards before you put the wood on, so this is less likely to happen again

Comment: What is the best way to "seal" the ends and back? Just make sure it gets painted well, or are there any proper ways of doing this?

Comment: If you are going to paint it, just use an outdoor primer, or even a deck sealer.  I think it is happening because the door has a lot of movement and I do not see any fasteners, probably just used liquid nails or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Western Red Cedar. Falling off is just Shoddy workmanship. I built my own garage doors 25 years ago and they still look like new.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears to be decorative not structual you could use Trex or some other brand of decay resistant manmade board

Comment: The disadvantage of Trex is it is heavy, certainly so compared to the cedar that was originally there. The difference may be enough that you would then need to adjust the springs used to balance the door. And if torsion springs are used, be VERY careful.